# Field of complex algebraic numbers

Tags: galois-theory

This is one of my mid-term problems:

> Let $E$ be the set of all complex elements of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e, $E$ = {u $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$|u is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$}. Prove that:
>
> a) $E$ is an algebraic and infinite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> b) $E$ is a normal and seperable extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

My answer for this problem is as follow:

a) $E$ is clearly an algebraic extension since all of its elements are algebraic.

Next, we suppose that E is finite, that means E is a finite vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Assume that [$E$:$\mathbb{Q}$] = n, then it has a basis of {$\alpha_{1}$;$\alpha_{2}$;...;$\alpha_{n}$}

b) For normality, I attempt to show that if a polynomial p(x) has root $u$ in $E$, then it's other roots {$u_{1};u_{2};...;u_{n}$} are all so in $E$, but how to do that then I have no idea.

In terms of seperability, I'm using a result:

> If char $E$ = 0 then every irreducible polynomial in $E[x]$ is seperable

Can I get any hint for this problem please?

Comment: For (b): All the roots of $\;p\;$ are in $\;E\;$ **by definition**, aren't they? And $\;E/\Bbb Q\;$ is infinite since for all $\;n\in\Bbb N\,,\,\,x^n-2\;$ is irreducible. Fill in details

Comment: In part (b) you must specify that the polynomial $p$ is in $\Bbb Q[x]$ and irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. After all, $(x-u)(x-\pi)$ is a polynomial with $u$ as a root, but not all its roots are algebraic numbers.